# Unity system time for android System.DateTime.now doesn't work?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, time

I made this code that works fine on the editor but not on my phone. I used unity 2017.4.3.
The problem is that when the app is closed in the andriod device, it doesnt feel it at all but it works fine in the editor so why doesn't "System.DateTime.now" doesn't work in the andriod device is is there away to make it work?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;

public class TimeMaster : MonoBehaviour {

    DateTime currentDate;
    DateTime oldDate;

    public string saveLocation;
    public static TimeMaster instance;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Awake () {

        instance = this;

        saveLocation = "LastSavedDate1";
    }

    public float CheckDate()
    {
        currentDate = System.DateTime.Now;
        string tempString = PlayerPrefs.GetString (saveLocation, "1");

        long tempLong = Convert.ToInt64 (tempString);

        DateTime oldDate = DateTime.FromBinary (tempLong);
        print ("oldDate : " + oldDate);

        TimeSpan difference = currentDate.Subtract (oldDate);
        print ("difference :" + difference);

        return(float)difference.TotalSeconds;

    }

    public void SaveDate ()
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetString (saveLocation, System.DateTime.Now.ToBinary ().ToString ());
        print ("saving this date to player prefs" + System.DateTime.Now);
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

and the rest in the level manager script

```
if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey ("lifeTime"))
{    
            newLifeTime = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("lifeTime");
            if (CountAllLives) 
            {
                newLifeTime -= TimeMaster.instance.CheckDate ();
            }

}
```

another part of the script

```
void OnApplicationQuit()
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("PlayerLives",currentLives);
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat ("lifeTime",newLifeTime);
    TimeMaster.instance.SaveDate ();
    print ("the count down is :" + newLifeTime);           
}
```

Comment: Can you make it more clear exactly what are you trying to do?

Comment: there is a timer to increase how many lives the player has so this script is for when the player closes the app it check the date/system time and save it so when the player comes back to the game it check the date/time again and compare it to the old one then it give the difference (new date/time - old date/time), as u can see from the code it minus difference from the lives timer so its like the lives timer didnt stop even when the player closed the app. as i said it works fine in the editor just not on the actual andriod device
so simply the question is why System.DateTime.Now doesn't work?

Comment: if its still not clear, the problem is DateTime.Now doesn't work on the andriod device is there anyway to make a script that does work on it?

Comment: It's definitely not clear what you mean by "System.DateTime.Now doesn't work" - you haven't said what it *does* do compared with what you *expect* it to do. (I would say that it's a bad property to use for measuring time differences - it observes time zone offset changes. You should almost certainly use `DateTime.UtcNow` instead. But without knowing what you mean by "doesn't work" it's hard to help you beyond that.)

Comment: I'm sorry that it wasn't clear for you anyways it has been asnwered so thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a dummy scene to implement your functionality and it worked fine for both editor and android device. 
One thing you need to make sure is to call `Application.Quit();` while quitting, because in case of android devices the `OnApplicationQuit` executes only when you call `Application.Quit();` unlike the editor were this is called when the user stops playmode.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnApplicationQuit.html

Comment: Oh thanks man I didn't know that... thanks I'll test it and hope all goes fine. What I understood from the link i should figure out where is the "exit on suspend" option or I should use application pause instead of quit so if the player pause the qame or suspend it, it still works.. ill test that thanks man!!!

Comment: Glad to help you !

Comment: just wanted to say it works perfectly thanks again! i just edited some stuff to make it all work however u shined the light for it!