# How can I convert a string to DateTime in Unity?

Tags: c#, datetime, unity-game-engine

I'm currently working on a virtual pet game, and I need help to solve this issue, as fast as possible.
I'm trying to get the `timeSpan` of between now and the last time I've played, and the script doesn't continue after the part of the `timeSpan` (Mentioned below the script, including the main question).
The Script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Bird : MonoBehaviour {

    [SerializeField]
    private int _hunger;
    [SerializeField]
    private int _happiness;
    [SerializeField]
    private string _name;

    private bool _servertime;
    private int _clickCount;

    DateTime timeSpan4;
    void Start()
    {
        print("Then: " + PlayerPrefs.GetString("then"));
        print("getStringTime(): " + getStringTime());
        print("TimeOfDay: " + DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay);
        print("DateTime now: " + DateTime.Now);
        //PlayerPrefs.SetString("then", "09 / 12 / 2019 20:50:0");
        updateStatus();
        //if (!PlayerPrefs.HasKey("name"))
        //    PlayerPrefs.SetString("name", "Bird");
        _name = PlayerPrefs.GetString("name");
    }

    void Update()
    {
        GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("Fly", gameObject.transform.position.y > -2.3);

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            //Debug.Log("Clicked");
            Vector2 v = new Vector2(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y);
            RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(v), Vector2.zero);
            if (hit)
            {
                //Debug.Log(hit.transform.gameObject.name);
                if(hit.transform.gameObject.tag == "Birb")
                {
                    _clickCount++;
                    if(_clickCount >= 3)
                    {
                        _clickCount = 0;
                        updateHappiness(5);
                        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(0, 1000));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void updateStatus()
    {
        print("Updating Status...");
        if (!PlayerPrefs.HasKey("_hunger"))
        {
            _hunger = 100;
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("_hunger", _hunger);
        }
        else
        {
            _hunger = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("_hunger");
        }

        if (!PlayerPrefs.HasKey("_happiness"))
        {
            _happiness = 100;
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("_happiness", _happiness);
        }
        else
        {
            _happiness = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("_happiness");
        }

        if (!PlayerPrefs.HasKey("then"))
            PlayerPrefs.SetString("then", getStringTime());

        TimeSpan ts = getTimeSpan();

        _hunger -= (int)(ts.TotalHours * 2);
        if (_hunger < 0)
        {
            _hunger = 0;
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("_hunger", _hunger);
        }
        if (_hunger > 100)
        {
            _hunger = 100;
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("_hunger", _hunger);
            print("hunger is bigger than 100!");
        }

        _happiness -= (int)((100 - _hunger) * (ts.TotalHours / 5));
        if (_happiness < 0)
        {
            _happiness = 0;
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("_happiness", _happiness);
        }
        if (_happiness > 100)
        {
            _happiness = 0;
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("_happiness", _happiness);
        }

        //Debug.Log(getTimeSpan().ToString());
        //Debug.Log(getTimeSpan().TotalHours);

        if (_servertime)
            updateServer();
        else
            InvokeRepeating("saveBird", 0f, 2f);
    }

    void updateServer()
    {

    }
    void updateDevice()
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("then", getStringTime());
    }

    TimeSpan getTimeSpan()
    {
        if (_servertime)
            return new TimeSpan();
        else
            return DateTime.Now - Convert.ToDateTime(PlayerPrefs.GetString("then"));
    }

    string getStringTime()
    {
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        return now.Day + "-" + now.Month + "-" + now.Year + " " + now.Hour + ":" + now.Minute + ":" + now.Second;
    }
    public int hunger
    {
        get { return _hunger; }
        set { _hunger = value; }
    }
    public int happiness
    {
        get { return _happiness; }
        set { _happiness = value; }
    }

    public string BName
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }

    public void updateHappiness(int i)
    {
        happiness += i;
        if (happiness > 100)
            happiness = 100;
    }
    public void saveBird()
    {
        if (!_servertime)
            updateDevice();
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("_hunger", _hunger);
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("_happiness", _happiness);
    }
}
```

The problem is in line 134 (`return DateTime.Now - Convert.ToDateTime(PlayerPrefs.GetString("then"));`), it prints `FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.`, and because of that the script doesn't continue after that part. How can I convert the string `"then"` to a `DateTime` so it won't error?

Comment: How are you saving the date time? as normally it wouldnt have spaces in ... what is the value of "then" ?? you have the right function

Comment: string getStringTime() { Datetime.now.toString();}

Comment: I'm trying to convert the string to DateTime, not the DateTime to string... (```PlayerPrefs.GetString("then")``` to DateTime, "then" = 12/13/2019 0:3:5, idk why the 0:3:5 isn't hour:minute,second)

Comment: 0:3:5 isnt really a time format.. or not normally, normally its 00:03:05, which is probably why its complaining.. What you can do is force then to be written in a given format, and read it back in that format..

Comment: I've [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57509475/how-to-check-if-time-passed-or-not-when-game-re-opened/57511214#57511214) a similar question before.

Comment: I think [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59165345/unity-system-time-for-android-system-datetime-now-doesnt-work/59171018#59171018) has implemented the functionality and might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact format for loading a date from a string depends on a lot of factors. One of the most important being the `locale`.

That being said you're a lot safer if you use `DateTimes` string formatting methods instead of saving it by hand.

You can change your `getStringTime()` to rely on `ToString` and save that:

```
string getStringTime() {
  return DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

Comment: But I want to subtract DateTime.Now by the String "then", and I can't do it when they're both Strings. But, as I saw, you can subtract DateTimes.

Comment: The problem is not the ```getStringTime()```, it's the ```getTimeSpan()```

Comment: `getTimeSpan` relies on a string representation of a DateTime saved earlier by using `getStringTime`. It fails because the string cannot be converted to a `DateTime`. You solve this by saving a correct string representation of a `DateTime` object.